# Multiple OAuth2AuthorizedClientManagers in a single Spring Boot application in Spring Security 5.8

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We are in the process of upgrading to Spring Security `5.8` in preparation for the bigger update to `6` and have the case where we require multiple `AuthorizedClientManager`s in a single Spring Boot application. I haven't been able to fin conclusive guides on this topic, so I'm hoping that some community feedback will be helpful.

We are using the Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka Server for service discovery (a bit old, I know) and have deployed [Spring Boot Admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) within the same application. We are using Keycloak as our OAuth2 authorization server.

The basic premise is this:

1. Spring Boot Admin has a service account that it can use to make backend requests to e.g. `/actuator` endpoints.
2. Access *to* the SBA UI is secured behind a login mask that requires a user login to view.

Before Spring Security 5.8, we were able to do this by following [this](https://www.codecentric.de/wissens-hub/blog/securing-spring-boot-admin-actuator-endpoints-keycloak) guide on setting up secured SBA access.

Now, we have the following:

```yaml
---
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        prefer-ip: true
      context-path: /admin
  security.oauth2.client:
    # UI client
    provider.external.issuer-uri: ${SBA_AUTH_SERVER_URL}/realms/${REALM}
    registration.external:
      provider: external
      token-uri: ${SBA_AUTH_SERVER_URL}/realms/${REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token
      client-name: spring-boot-admin-ui
      client-id: spring-boot-admin
      scope: openid,offline_access,profile,email
      authorization-grant-type: authorization_code

    # SBA Service account client
    provider.sba.issuer-uri: ${SBA_AUTH_SERVER_URL}/realms/${REALM}
    registration.sba:
      provider: sba
      token-uri: ${SBA_AUTH_SERVER_URL}/realms/${REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token
      client-name: spring-boot-admin
      client-id: spring-boot-admin
      client-secret: ${SBA_CLIENT_SECRET}
      authorization-grant-type: client_credentials


jwt:
  auth:
    converter:
      resource-id: spring-boot-admin
      principal-attribute: preferred_username
```

Together with the following configurations:

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ManagerConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService auth2AuthorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientServiceAndManager (
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        return new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository,
                authorizedClientService);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = 
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);

        authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.DefaultContextAttributesMapper());

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final String apiToken;

    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
    private final AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientServiceAndManager;


    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(@Value("${SBA_API_TOKEN}") final String apiToken,
                             final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                             final AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientServiceAndManager) {
        this.apiToken = apiToken;
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
        this.authorizedClientServiceAndManager = authorizedClientServiceAndManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .oauth2Client()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .tokenEndpoint()
                .and()
                .userInfoEndpoint().userAuthoritiesMapper(new MyAuthoritiesMapper());
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/*/*.css", "/admin/img/**", "/admin/third-party/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        http.logout(httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer -> {
            httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.clearAuthentication(true);
            httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.invalidateHttpSession(true);
            httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/logout"));
            httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler());
        });
        return http.build();
    }

    private LogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);

        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}");

        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }

    /**
     * {@link HttpHeadersProvider} used to populate the {@link HttpHeaders} for
     * accessing the state of the discovered clients.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public HttpHeadersProvider keycloakBearerAuthHeaderProvider() {
        return provider -> {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("X-Api-Token", apiToken);
            OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("sba")
                    .principal("spring-boot-admin")
                    .build();

            OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.authorizedClientServiceAndManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = Objects.requireNonNull(authorizedClient).getAccessToken();
            headers.add("X-Authorization-Token", "keycloak-bearer "
                    + authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());

            return headers;

        };
    }
}
```

This works for the service account that the internal Spring Boot Admin application uses to perform the various `/actuator/**` invocations.

However, I'm having trouble setting up a *separate* client and `AuthorizedClientManager` for displaying a login mask upon navigating. Specifically, adding this part of the configuration:

```java
               .authorizeHttpRequests()
               .requestMatchers("/*/*.css", "/admin/img/**", "/admin/third-party/**").permitAll()
               .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

makes the `/admin` path (which is supposed to redirect to our Keycloak login page) yield just the following blank page:

[image]

I imagine this is because I haven't actually *configured* which `AuthorizedClientManager` should be used in this login process.

I'm still familiarizing myself with all of the Spring Security OAuth2 API, but I believe that the core problem is that I require *both* a:

- `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` for the normal session-based login (user navigates to UI, gets redirected, logs in), and a
- `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` which is used for background-threads and `client_credentials` based logins.

and then have to customize my `SecurityFilterChain` with:

```java
                .oauth2Client(httpSecurityOAuth2ClientConfigurer ->
                        httpSecurityOAuth2ClientConfigurer.authorizedClientService(...))
```

but the `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` does not expose the underlying `AuthorizedClientService`.

How can I proceed in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about **not** exposing the `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` as a `@Bean` (the only `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` bean in DI being the `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager`, as "normal" for an application processing HTTP requests)?

You could modify your `HttpHeadersProvider` as follow:

```java
@Component
public static class KeycloakBearerAuthHeaderProvider implements HttpHeadersProvider {

    private final String apiToken;
    private final AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

    public KeycloakBearerAuthHeaderProvider(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService,
            @Value("${SBA_API_TOKEN}") String apiToken) {
        this.apiToken = apiToken;
        this.authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders(Instance provider) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("X-Api-Token", apiToken);
        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("sba").principal("spring-boot-admin").build();

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = Objects.requireNonNull(authorizedClient).getAccessToken();
        headers.add("X-Authorization-Token", "keycloak-bearer " + accessToken.getTokenValue());

        return headers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this approach worked well and I've got it working again. To be honest, it doesn't really feel like this is the intended usage (especially since I *still* need the client registrations configs to pass in client-id and secret), but I'll just live with it for now. Thanks!